# Where are the "tools" and "platform-tools" directories located inside Linux Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I usually do Android development on Windows, with Android SDK. My supervisor just askmed me to build an open source mobile app, which build environment runs only on Linux and Mac.

I don't have dedicated Linux/Mac box, but there's a Debian VPS (no desktop environment BTW, just text mode). So first I grabbed the Android command line tools for Linux (sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip), unzipped it to **/root/android-sdk**. Then installed some packages via **sdkmanager**
[image]

Interestingly, there are no **platform-tools** and **tools** directories inside **/android-sdk**
[image]

So where are they?

Comment: from your first screenshot, it seems like it should be inside `bin` folder

Comment: @VivekMishra I just found that the `tools`, `build-tools`, `platform-tools` etc directories are located in `/root`, not `/root/android-sdk`. Hmm...